# Discard views filter on field from referenced taxonomy term when relationship isn't present

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms, views

I want to show two content types (A and B) in one view. 'A' has a relationship with a taxonomy term 'foo', 'B' doesn't have this relationship. So the relationship isn't required. However when I use a field from 'foo' as a filter in the filter criteria no nodes of content type B are shown, the nodes of content type A are shown correctly.

Is it possible to configure the view such that it doesn't look at the filter with the referenced field for nodes of content type B?

If something isn't clear, ask me!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you want to use *Grouped Filters* in Views. In the View UI, there's an *Add/Or, Rearrange* option next to the **Filter Criteria** section.

This allows you to create a complex grouping of filters. To use an example that matches your conditions, here's a setup using Drupal's Standard installation with *Basic Page*/*Article* nodes and *Tags* taxonomy that's exclusive to *Article*:

[image]

Comment: I didn't know this views feature, heh, just when you think you know it all.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but I already tried this. It doesn't seem to work.